# Getting error in concourse hijack: Backend error: Exit status: 500

Tags: cloud-foundry, concourse, concourse-git-resource, cf-bosh

I am getting below error while working on concourse:

> hijack: Backend error: Exit status: 500, message:
>   {"Type":"","Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed:
>   container_linux.go:264: starting container process caused \"exec:
>   \\"./task-scripts/task_show_uname.sh\\": stat
>   ./task-scripts/task_show_uname.sh: no such file or
>   directory\"\n","Handle":""}

I have a task.yml:

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: task-scripts

run:
  path: ./task-scripts/task_show_uname.sh

***************

task_show_uname.sh runs a simple "uname -a" command.

***************
```

pipeline.yml looks like:

```
resources:
- name: resource-tutorial
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/manmohan1391/concourse-tutorial.git
    branch: master

jobs:
- name: job-hello-world
  public: true
  plan:
  - task: hello-world
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: busybox}
      run:
        path: echo
        args:
        - hello world

- name: scripts
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: resource-tutorial
  - task: script-hello
    file: resource-tutorial/tutorials/basic/task-scripts/task_show_uname.yml
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question, not a link to your github master, as this will change, preventing people learning from this question.

Answer (score 1):

if your pipeline goes orange instead of red, it means the hijack failed to create and you can't hijack it. Looking at your task yml in the question:

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: task-scripts

run:
  path: ./task-scripts/task_show_uname.sh
```

Given with your pipeline definition, it should probably look like this:

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: resource-tutorial

run:
  path: resource-tutorial/tutorials/basic/task-scripts/task_show_uname.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run hijack? It looks like you're trying to have fly run your script instead of a shell. The hijack command tries to run bash by default and if the docker image doesn't have bash, just have hijack run 'sh'.